# Prevent remote computer from locking screen after timeout

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, lock-screen, timeout

I'm connecting from a Windows 10 Pro machine at home to another Windows 10 Pro at work.
After doing nothing for 5 min the work machine goes into screen lock.
I can't change the timeout because the company policy says so.
While the policy makes total sense at work it has no value at home because there's nobody in my flat that could do damage to the system (except for myself.. and the cat)

So how can I fool the work computer into thinking that I'm active?
Preferrably without an external tool (I tried Move-Mouse from MS but I failed to install it).

Comment: When you violate IT policy, consider your job...

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, I already addressed that concern in my post

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-prevent-lock-screen-timeout-when-idle/) great solution that I want to share because it's so simple. Just paste the following lines into a powershell window on the work machine or save them as a .ps1 file and run it from file explorer by invoking "Run with PowerShell".
Adapt the sleep duration (in seconds) to your needs, it just has to be smaller than the timeout setting on your work machine.

```
$WShell = New-Object -Com Wscript.Shell
while (1) {
    $WShell.SendKeys("{SCROLLLOCK}")
    sleep 60
}
```